# remove 0 values in array and adjust size

Tags: java

so I have

```
int[] a = {0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 3, 9};
int[] b = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3};
```

how can I get it so that all elements with a value of 0 are erased and each array doesn't have any extra unnecessary space allocated.

```
int[] a = {4, 2, 3, 9};
int[] b = {1, 3};
```

Comment: Are you required to use arrays or can you use an ArrayList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 8 solution:

```
a = Arrays.stream(a).filter(v -> v != 0).toArray();
```

Solution not requiring Java 8:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    if (a[i] != 0)
        a[count++] = a[i];
a = Arrays.copyOf(a, count);
```

However, I think the best solution is to use an `ArrayList<Integer>` for this sort of thing.